# How to trace back ANR when you cant even find any class path in logs?

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

Below is what I got in logs. Dont know what this logs means.

> Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send key event because the focused window has not finished processing all of the input events that were previously delivered to it. Outbound queue length: 0. Wait queue length: 1.), VisibleToUser

```
"main" tid=1 Native

"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x73baef60 self=0xa6b12000 | sysTid=10645 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaa7cd494 | state=S schedstat=( 1907040905 256895069 3521 ) utm=150 stm=39 core=7 HZ=100 | stack=0xbe50f000-0xbe511000 stackSize=8MB | held mutexes=

#00 pc 0000000000019d34 /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)

#01 pc 00000000000a6b6b /system/lib/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+78)

#02 pc 000000000026a895 /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallObjectMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+352)

#03 pc 0000000000098825 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeDisplayEventReceiver::dispatchVsync(long long, int, unsigned int)+20)

#04 pc 00000000000327d9 /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::DisplayEventDispatcher::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+100)

#05 pc 000000000000f239 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+632)

#06 pc 000000000000ef43 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+26)

#07 pc 00000000000b8bdb /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long, int)+24)

at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)

at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:326)

at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:169)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6939)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)

at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:870)
```

Comment: did you check all of the threads? it usually does a thread dump, and there are always at least 12 threads running at the same time.

Comment: Actually yes there were multiple threads. But as it is production ANR i dont get much to see. Thought posting whole output here might not be a good idea

Comment: put it in a pastebin, and post the link

Comment: here's the [link](https://pastebin.com/9GVBwePH) to some of more detailed output.